# PostSharp Multicast not working in Outlook plugin code

Tags: c#, logging, postsharp

I am using PostSharp in an Outlook Plugin app. If I add the following attribute to a class in my project it logs properly:

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{
[Log(AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
public class FooBar {...}
}
```

What I really want to do is log everything in the Foo.* namespace. I tried using the addin in VS which created a globalaspects.cs and updated my project.pssln file. At this point it wont build with the following error msg:

> .dll uses non-licensed features (PostSharp Professional). Please enter a valid license key.

I figured it was recursing on itself so I added an AttributeExclude = true in the assembly line that was generated for me. It now looks like this (in globalaspects.cs):

`[assembly: Log(AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetTypes = "Foo.*",      AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]`

No luck, it doesn't log anything this way. Any ideas why?

Additional info:
I am logging to log4net and I have other logging code that is working (it also works at both the class and method levels with PostSharp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.postsharp.net/purchase) free license of PostSharp currently has limitation on number of methods on which `[Log]` attribute is applied. In my opinion, you have exceeded this number by applying the aspect on the whole namespace.

`AttributeExclude` means that the attribute will not be applied on declarations that satisfy conditions set in this attribute. It is basically set inclusion/exclusion operation. For example you can include `Namespace1`, exclude `Namespace1.Namespace2` and again include `Namespace1.Namespace2.Namespace3`.

Therefore the following would be correct:

```
[assembly: Log(AttributeTargetTypes = "Foo.*",
               AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, 
               AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
```

For more information about attribute multicasting, you can take a look on [this article](http://doc.postsharp.net/multicast-conceptual).

Note to reviewers: I'm one of developers working on PostSharp. I'm aware that this answer touches licensing, which is behind the red line and I have tried my best not to cross it too much.